# Is there an ADB command to check a media is playing or not

Tags: android, shell, terminal, adb

I want to check whether the Audio/Video is playing in my external device which is rooted in terminal using ADB command.I am not able to find any ADB commands if available mention that

I have tried                                                                                                                               adb shell dumpsys media.player

i want a command to specify if video is running or not

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command to find a list of active media sessions with some information about each session:

```
adb shell dumpsys media_session
```

In the output, `state` field reflects the state of the playback. This is an example output:

```
state=PlaybackState {state=3, position=793945, buffered position=843968, speed=1.0, updated=8327704, actions=2360143, custom actions=[], active item id=-1, error=null}
```

where `state=3` means that the media is playing. Refer to [PlaybackState documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/PlaybackState) for different state constants.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no direct command to do that. But you can query all the running service using

```
adb shell service list | grep 'media.player'
```

Comment: i want only to check in current window

Comment: You can get the most recent activity details from 'adb shell dumpsys activity'.

Comment: i am not getting activity for media player'

Answer (score 0):

To print out the MediaPlayer states:

```
adb shell dumpsys audio
```

But this will show the output of entire device. Like so:

```
06-25 14:11:02:226 new player piid:1343 uid/pid:10080/26372 type:android.media.MediaPlayer attr:AudioAttributes: usage=USAGE_UNKNOWN content=CONTENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN flags=0x0 tags= bundle=null
06-25 14:11:02:249 player piid:1343 state:started
06-25 14:35:13:911 releasing player piid:1343
06-25 14:35:20:570 new player piid:1351 uid/pid:10080/29715 type:android.media.MediaPlayer attr:AudioAttributes: usage=USAGE_UNKNOWN content=CONTENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN flags=0x0 tags= bundle=null
06-25 14:35:20:598 player piid:1351 state:started
06-25 14:35:29:720 releasing player piid:1351
06-25 14:36:34:263 new player piid:1359 uid/pid:10080/29715 type:android.media.MediaPlayer attr:AudioAttributes: usage=USAGE_UNKNOWN content=CONTENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN flags=0x0 tags= bundle=null
06-25 14:36:34:304 player piid:1359 state:started
```

You can use this to get the PID of your app and then check the state of the MediaPlayer:

```
adb shell pidof -s your.package.name
```

Answer (score 0):

**`dumpsys media.audio_flinger`** shows a lot more information about individual raw  audio I/O devices. Each output goes into standby after about a second of no audio being played (no idea if this is device-dependent, I tested on a Moto G8 plus):

```
Output thread 0x70bad82100, name AudioOut_D, tid 3373, type 0 (MIXER):
  I/O handle: 13
  Standby: yes
  ...
```

In the `Hal stream dump` section there is a `Signal power history` which shows more details, but this standby yes/no indicator was enough for me. I didn't bother parsing the sections by output device and just used:

```
dumpsys media.audio_flinger | grep "   Standby: no" | wc -l
```

This counts how many devices are not in standby, echoing `1` when no audio is playing (mic is always listening ) and `2` or higher when any audio output is active.

---

The other answers didn't work for me, because I'm using 'cast receiver' apps that do not create a media player/session, so the output of `dumpsys media_session` looks like this:

```
Record for full_user=0
  ...
  Media button session is null
  ...
Audio playback (lastly played comes first)
  uid=10240 packages=com.softmedia.receiver
  uid=10230 packages=com.ionitech.airscreen
```

Answer (score 0):

For 4.1.1 Jellybean.  Depends if media is **online** or **offline**.

For **Online** audio:

```
adb shell su -c "dumpsys media.audio_flinger | grep 'AudioMixer tracks: 00000003' | wc -l"
```

Returns `1` if audio is playing and `0` if audio is not playing.

For **Offline** Audio:

```
adb shell su -c "dumpsys media.player | grep 'active(1)' | wc -l"
```

or

```
adb shell su -c "dumpsys media.player | grep 'state(0)' | wc -l"
```

Returns `1` if audio is playing and `0` if audio is not playing.

Answer (score 0):

The following command will display the current proces that is has an active media session. a.k.a. is playing music/video

```
adb shell dumpsys media_session | perl -0777 -ne 'print "$1\n" if /sessions:\s+(\w+)(?=.*state=3)/s'
```

It will display for example:

```
spotify
```

or

```
netflix
```