# Is it possible to detect a tone like a message alert from an app on Android devices using adb?

Tags: java, android, adb

Is it possible to detect whether a sound/tone occurred on an Android device such as from an app notification? Would this work using adb, possibly by looking through certain logs?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241551/is-there-an-adb-command-to-check-a-media-is-playing-or-not)
I think that the best way is to create an app that runs in the background and monitors if a sound has occurred.
By looking at the adb logs you cant always have to exact moment that the sound happens